# Jquery masonry doesn't work well : the left postion is incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I try to use masonry for a image wall. I use % for xolumn width and there is a problem with the left postion of the image.

i created the grid and set the item

```
<div  class="grid">            
      <div class="grid-item grid-sizer loaded"><img src="images/home/10-idol-anthonymeyer.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid-item grid-sizer loaded"><img src="images/home/13-fiasco-anthonymeyer.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid-item grid-sizer loaded"><img src="images/home/15-redcollector-alvarez.jpg.png"></div>
      <div class="grid-item grid-sizer loaded"><img src="images/home/21-fiasco.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid-item grid-sizer loaded"><img src="images/home/24-dirty-breton.jpg.png"></div>
     .....
</div>
```

Javascript as follow

```
$(document).ready( function() {
// masonry
    $('.grid').masonry({
      // options
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        //percentPosition: true,
    });
}
```

And CSS

```
.grid {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: no;
    padding: 0;    
}

.grid-sizer, .grid-item{
    width: 19%;
}

.grid-item {    

    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.grid-item img {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

The left position of the first images is correct but no the position of the second. For exemple with a size of 1200px the left postion is 0 and the postion of the second must approximatively 243px but in my page i have this

```
1th image : <div style="position: absolute; **left: 0px;** top: 0px;" class="grid-item grid-sizer "><img src="images/home/10-idol-anthonymeyer.jpg"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; **left: 320px;** top: 0px;" class="grid-item grid-sizer "><img src="images/home/13-fiasco-anthonymeyer.jpg"></div>
```

I can find what is wrong with my code eand how to fix the problem. Could you help me please.

Comment: did you use the imagesloaded plugin to make sure you call the masonry plugin after image loading is complete?

Comment: No i didn't. I'm going to try. Thnak you

Comment: The solution works. Thank you.